# On boot i have black screen with text `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS localhost tty1`

Tags: python

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS localhost tty1 localhost login: yuliia
 Password: 
etc/update-notd.d/80-esm: 3: etc/update notd.d/80-esm: Isb release: not found 
etc/update-notd.d/80-esm: 4: etc/update notd.d/ 80-esm: Isb release: not found 
etc/update-notd.d/ 91-release-upgrade: 4: etc/update notd.d/91- release-upgrade: Isb release: not found
 Welcone to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS CGNLinux 4.15.0 43 generic x86 64)
```

I tried update python, but removed it then again installed. After reboot i see black screen. Help me please!

Comment: It says "Welcone (sic) to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS", so Ubuntu works, you just got dropped into terminal somehow. Are there any more error messages? I don't think this has to do with Python. You probably deleted a file you shouldn't've touched. This question may better fit https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ye, i think i deleted some files and now it shiw me black screen. I dont know how to download them back. And i have this msg at start.

Comment: Do you know what files you deleted _exactly_ and where you deleted them from?

Comment: No. I removed python and installed it. Then reboot pc and now i have this screen.

Comment: How did you remove it? How did you install it? Have you tried switching the computer off and on again? Are there any more error messages?

Comment: I used `sudo apt remove python3` then `sudo apt-get install python3`. I dont have any error msgs.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168736/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line).

Comment: i need 10 points to put a photo.

Comment: you can always post links to photos. Did you try the possible solution in my link? Your Ubuntu works, but without a graphical interface. You should still have access to your files, your Python installation, the Internet (if I’m not mistaken, there’s even a console browser called `lynx` that you can use to surf the net) and whatnot.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/551132829942153230/556172113317330965/P90315-1536471.jpg

Comment: How to get back a graphical interface?

Comment: can you run `startx` in this terminal? A.k.a. type that in and hit Enter

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/551132829942153230/556175294126620684/P90315-200013.jpg?width=638&height=473

Comment: `sudo startx` should fix that

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/551132829942153230/556176610072592398/P90315-200705.jpg

Comment: The lesson here is: **don't use `sudo apt remove python3`**! That will not only remove the `python3` package, it will uninstall **all packages on your system** that depend on `python3`, even transitively. At this point, you're probably better off re-installing your Ubuntu system from scratch.

Comment: I'd say you messed up, mate( You can check whether any of that helps: https://medium.com/@hicraigchen/how-to-get-my-ubuntu-18-0-4-gui-back-from-tty-4ce73db8e103 https://askubuntu.com/questions/403747/how-to-access-gui-from-tty-mode

Comment: Here's a cross-site duplicate on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/437644/i-accidentaly-did-sudo-apt-get-remove-python

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/796598/why-did-removing-python3-remove-many-other-important-packages

Comment: Thanks guys for try to help. Maybe i will reinstall Ubuntu.